# No hyperlink when there should be using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I am creating a form using Google Sheets and have been using Google Apps Script to create buttons for the form. I was just writing to query why whenever I use the script below, the link that **SHOULD** create the PDF doesn't show as a link at all, just the word 'This' and nothing else, not hyperlinked or anything.

Here is the script:

```
function printPdf() {
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

    var gid = sheet.getSheetId();

    var pdfOpts = '&size=A4&fzr=false&portrait=true&fitw=true&gridlines=false&printtitle=false&sheetnames=false&pagenum=UNDEFINED&attachment=false&gid='+gid;


    var row2 = 56;
    var printRange = '&c1=0' + '&r1=0' + '&c2=7' + '&r2='+row2; // B2:APn
    var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + pdfOpts + printRange;

      var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(100).setHeight(25);
    app.setTitle('Click the link below to open as PDF');

    var link = app.createAnchor('Open PDF', url).setTarget('_new');

    app.add(link);

    ss.show(app);
     }
```

[This image below shows a screenshot of what I am talking about when I say there's no link to open the PDF.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhnO7.jpg)

This works when I use one Google account but whenever I use any other accounts, the link doesn't work. My manager also tried with his Google account once I had shared it with him and it does not work for him either. The script has all the authoritative permissions needed to work and I can't spot any permission differences between one Google account that works and one that doesn't. I have even tried transferring ownership of the sheet to an account that does not work and still no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: What does the execution transcript show (View>execution transcript) in the script editor for working version and non-working version? Also Uiapp is deprecated I.e. not supported or recommended by google. Use dialog box as mentioned in google developers page instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time running your script on a new spreadsheet it shows the link fine for me.
I would consider switching to html service as ui is deprecated.

```
UiApp API is deprecated.Expand
File: Code Line: 15
Anchor API is deprecated.Expand
File: Code Line: 18
UiInstance API is deprecated.Expand
File: Code Line: 15
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don't I feel silly! I was looking into this just now and noticed the slight black top of more text underneath the word 'This'. I then went into the script and made the application box's size 400 x 100 instead of 100 x 25 and more text was revealed to say 'This application was created by another user, not by Google.' with the actual hyperlink UNDERNEATH that text. Oh boy...